# Scapy How to create custom protocol/packet structure?

Tags: scapy

Can someone please help me with an example code.
I would like to use scapy to create this packet structure:

```
MyPacketStructure:
  field1: 2 bytes
  field2: 16 bytes
  field3: 12 bytes
  field4: 17 bytes
  data: 83 bytes
```

How do I define a scapy class for the above packet structure?

```
class MyPacketStructure(Packet):
    what type do i use to set ("field1") for 2 bytes
    what type do i use to set ("field2") for 16 bytes
    what type do i use to set ("field3") for 12 bytes
    what type do i use to set ("field4") for 17 bytes
    what type do i use to set ("data") for 83 bytes
```

I see ByteField but it's only one byte.  Which scapy datatype let's me set the number of bytes for that field.

For the data field or payload, what is the recommended datatype?  What happens if i only 43 bytes?  How do I pad the other 40 bytes for the data field?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should really read the documentation. It is really well written especially for creating the new protocols - [Adding new protocols scapy](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_dissect.html)

Comment: I've got through the Disney example and read the doc but couldn't understand how to handle the 16 bytes worth of data for field2.

Comment: You can use `StrFixedLenField("field2", b"", length=16)`... etc